# How to get the inner text from an xml document using XDocument and extension methods

Tags: asp.net, linq, xml-parsing, extension-methods, xelement

I am trying to get the "NAME" and "EMAIL" texts from the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <font class="normal">
                <b>NAME</b> <a href="/member/mail_compose.aspx?id=name"><img src="/images/mailbox.gif" border="0" alt="Send Mail" /></a> <a href="/photos/member_viewphoto.aspx?id=name"><img src="/images/icons/member_photos.gif" border="0" alt="View  Photos" /></a> <br />
                ADDRESS<br />
                PHONE<br />
                <a href="mailto:email@hotmail.com" class="redlink">EMAIL</a><br />
                <br />
            </font>
        </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
// Load the xml document
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Directory.html");

// Parse document
var names = xDoc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf()
        .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ol").DescendantsAndSelf()
        .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "li").DescendantsAndSelf()
        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            name = x.Elements().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "b").Select(y => y.Value),
                            email = x.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "a" && x.FirstAttribute.Name == "href" && x.Attribute("href").Value.Contains("mailto")).Select(y => y.Value ?? "No Email")
                        }
        );

// Print text to console
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", names.ElementAt(i).name, names.ElementAt(i).email);
}
```

Somehow, the above code is printing this:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,
>   System.String]:
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xm
>   l.Linq.XElement,System.String]

Could someone please tell me why this is happening? Also, if there is a better way of doing this, suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question (which is probably more important to you than the code I have to get it working for that sample HTML), you have .Select for your name and email fields. That's why you're returning a collection when you loop over names. If that is actually what you want, then do a SelectMany instead of a Select when you create your anonymous object.

Without a schema, I don't know how to better your XML traversing before the ".Select"

Another issue is that for the href attribute, you need to compare to FirstAttribute.Name.LocalName instead of just the FirstAttribute.Name

```cs
var names = xDoc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ol").DescendantsAndSelf()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "li").DescendantsAndSelf()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "font")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    name = x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "b").Select(y => y.Value).Single(),
                    email = x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "a" && y.FirstAttribute.Name.LocalName == "href" && y.Attribute("href").Value.Contains("mailto")).Select(y => y.Value).Single()
                });
```

Some notes:

```
y.Value ?? "No Email"
```

needs to be redone because the y.Value will never be null

also you were missing an ol tag in your html :)

Answer (score 1):

Without checks for null (note most of the places I use FirstorDefault can potentially thrrow NullExceptions since I do not check for null in the solution.

```
var htmlToProcess = 
@"<!DOCTYPE html>
                                <html lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
                                <head>
                                    <meta charset='utf-8' />
                                    <title></title>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li>
                                            <font class='normal'>
                                                <b>NAME</b> <a href='/member/mail_compose.aspx?id=name'><img src='/images/mailbox.gif' border='0' alt='Send Mail' /></a> <a href='/photos/member_viewphoto.aspx?id=name'><img src='/images/icons/member_photos.gif' border='0' alt='View  Photos' /></a> <br />
                                                ADDRESS<br />
                                                PHONE<br />
                                                <a href='mailto:email@hotmail.com' class='redlink'>EMAIL</a><br />
                                                <br />
                                            </font>
                                        </li>
                                    </ol>
                                </body>
                                </html>";
        var body = dataSet1Tree.Nodes()
                               .OfType<XElement>()
                               .FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name.LocalName.ToLower() =="body");

        if (body != null)
        {
            var oi = body.Descendants()
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == "ol");
            if (oi != null)
            {
                var lis = oi.Elements()
                            .Where(x=> x.Name.LocalName.ToLower()=="li");
                var listContainingInfo =from font in lis.Select(li => body.Descendants()
                                                                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == "font"))
                                                        .Where(font => font != null) 
                                        select font.Nodes().OfType<XElement>();

                var listOfUsers = listContainingInfo.Select(nodes => new
                {
                    Name = nodes.FirstOrDefault(innerNode => innerNode.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == "b").Value,
                    Email = nodes.FirstOrDefault(innerNode => innerNode.Value == "EMAIL")
                                 .Attributes("href")
                                 .FirstOrDefault()
                                 .Value
                });

                foreach (var user in listOfUsers)
                    Console.WriteLine(user.Name +" "+ user.Email);


            }
        }
```

Comment: This answer also works, but I am marking the other correct answer as Answer because it was posted first. Thank you for your answer.